# Visual Studio 2015 code format issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

In VS 2015 options under `Text Editor > C# > Tabs` I set `Indenting` to `Smart` and checked option `Keep tabs`.

Now if I auto-format code, everything is formated as expected.
But the space before a comment is changed to spaces if there were tabs:

[image]

In previous versions of Visual Studio, tabs stays on auto code formatting.
There seems to be no option to change that behavior.

This is not an issue of beautification.
Its an issue for me, because auto-formated files are marked as different with our tool chain.

How can prevent this?

Comment: This is what the "Keep Tabs" option is for. Did you checked, that your C# setting is not overwritten in the "All Languages" -> "Tabs" settings?

Comment: The "All language settings" is set to the same options. Seems that "Keep tabs" is not working?

Comment: The Roslyn integration has been a massive bug generator, this was shipped before it was tested.  Testing is not agile.  Ensure you have Update 1 installed.  Then click the "New Issue" button on [this web page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8224).

This was stated as "intentional change".

Because files that has been auto-formated now has spaces instead of tabs, a huge amount of file differences show up in our tool chain. This is very hard to accept.